# geopandas reproject change the extent of the vector

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geopandas

`Geopandas` reproject changes the extent of the vector. Below is an example, you can download the vector file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w9LR7DquQ6QueU4cv04p3BWurHZ95GZL/view?usp=sharing)

```
# First please download the shp file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Read the file using geopandas
domain = geopandas.read_file("data.shp")

#Create a polygone
polygon = Polygon([(-100,62),(-170,62),(-170,64),(-100,64)])
poly_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[polygon], crs=domain.crs)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 8))
domain.plot(ax=ax1)
poly_gdf.boundary.plot(ax = ax1,color="red")
```

[image]

Now let's reproject both and plot them again:

```
# Reproject both polygons to Albers Equal Area projection
domain_reproj = domain.to_crs('+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs')
poly_gdf_reproj = poly_gdf.to_crs('+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs')

# And plot them again
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 8))
domain_reproj.plot(ax=ax1)
poly_gdf_reproj.boundary.plot(ax = ax1, color = 'red')
```

[image: the yellow circle shows the area of difference]

As you can after reprojecting both polygons to the same projection system the overlapping area changes. The yellow circles help to spot the difference. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geopandas is just re-projecting each of the points in your polygons ie "(-100,62),(-170,62),(-170,64),(-100,64)" rather than projecting along the line.

You can check that `poly_gdf.iloc[0].geometry.wkt` only give you five points where as you would expect a wide curve made from lots of small line segments in the projected map.

If you want a polygon that will project nicely one option is to add more points along each edge of your polygon.

As Michael suggested, you can do this really cleanly with shapely's `interpolate`

```
original_polygon = Polygon([(-100,62),(-170,62),(-170,64),(-100,64),(-100,62)])

polygon = Polygon([original_polygon.boundary.interpolate(i, normalized=True) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)])

poly_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[polygon], crs=domain.crs)
```

Comment: this is great! just noting that you can do this really cleanly with shapely's [`interpolate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.interpolate), e.g. `poly_interped = Polygon([original_polygon.boundary.interpolate(i, normalized=True) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)])`

Comment: Ohh, nice! Thats seems like it has the added benefit of distributing the points evenly around the polygon.

Edited to this method. Thanks!